# Proper detection of whitespaces using ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, whitespace, grammar

I am using ANTLR3, via the runtime available through Maven repo1.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar MiniJavax;

goal    :   mainClass EOF;

mainClass 
    :    'class' IDENTIFIER '{' methodDeclarations 'public' 'static' 'void' 'main' '(' ')'
    '{' varDeclarations statements '}' '}';

varDeclarations
    :   varDeclaration varDeclarations | ;

varDeclaration
    :   type IDENTIFIER ';' ;

methodDeclarations
    :   methodDeclaration methodDeclarations | ;

methodDeclaration
    :   'public' 'static' type IDENTIFIER '(' parameters ')' '{' varDeclarations statements
        'return' genExpression ';' '}'
    ;

parameters
    :   type IDENTIFIER parameter | ;

parameter 
    :   ',' type IDENTIFIER parameter | ;

type    :   'int' | 'boolean';

statements
    :   statement statements | ;

statement
    :   '{' statements '}'
    |   'if' '(' genExpression ')' statement 'else' statement
    |   'while' '(' genExpression ')' statement
    |   'System' '.' 'out' '.' 'println' '(' genExpression ')' ';'
    |   IDENTIFIER '=' genExpression ';';

genExpression
    :   expression genExpressionRest;

genExpressionRest
    :   relExpression | ;

expression
    :   term expressionRest;

expressionRest
    :   '+' term expressionRest | '-' term expressionRest | ;

term
    :   factor termRest;

termRest 
    :   '*' factor termRest | ;

factor
    :   '(' expression ')'
    |   IDENTIFIER
    |   IDENTIFIER '(' arguments ')'
    |   'true'
    |   'false'
    |   INTEGER;

relExpression
    :   '==' expression relExpressionRest | '<' expression relExpressionRest;

relExpressionRest
    :   '&&' relTerm relExpressionRest |;

relTerm
    :   '==' expression
    |   '<' expression;

arguments
    :   genExpression argument | ;

argument
    :   ',' genExpression argument | ;



IDENTIFIER  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;


INTEGER :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

As you can see, I have specified whitespace characters for the lexer, and have made it hidden to the parser through the HIDDEN channel.

However, when I try to parse this:

```
class PrintNumbers {
    public static void main() {
        int number;
        number = 1;
        while (number < 11) {
            System.out.println(number);
            number = number + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
line 1:5 extraneous input ' ' expecting IDENTIFIER
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't this be able to solve my problem?

BTW, I am generating the code using ANTLRWorks if that changes anything.

**UPDATE**: To avoid confusion I have included my whole grammar.

Comment: Why those ":" in single lines in the grammar?

Comment: They are supposed to denote there are rules omitted out of the grammar :D

Comment: I posted the whole thing. Thanks for the comments people.

Comment: And what about the input? Obviously, the colon in `class PrintNumbers {
    :
}` is wrong...

Comment: I had crossed it out, since the rest of it seemed irrelevant to my original question, however it's now included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that I was using a `BufferedTokenStream` instead of the usual `CommonTokenStream`. That's why the channel directive was being ignored here.

Comment: Good of you to post the solution. And here you see the importance of posting a question containing self-contained example code: as your question now stands, it is impossible for others to see what the problem is because you did not provide the driver class containing the use of the `BufferedTokenStream`.